# Clean memory after importing module in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks

I'm trying to clear the memory used after an import of a module in nodeJs (node version: v14.17.5). Getting the memory used with a `process.memoryUsage()`. I tried a couple of different things I found on internet, but I cannot go back to the size of the heap used before the import.

Here is a very simple snippet I'm using for my tests:

```
console.log("hello world")

logMemoryUsage("before express import");
let express = require("express");
logMemoryUsage("after express import");
////////////////////// try a couple of things
delete require.cache['express']
require.cache = {};
express = null;
for (const path in require.cache) {
    delete require.cache[path]
}
delete express;
delete require.cache[require.resolve('./node_modules/express/index.js')]
delete require.cache[require.resolve('express')]
//////////////////////
logMemoryUsage("after clear express");

function logMemoryUsage(msg) {
    const used = process.memoryUsage();
    let l = "";
    for (let key in used) {
      l += `${key} ${Math.round((used[key] / 1024 / 1024) * 100) / 100} MB, `;
    }
    console.log(`MEMORY_USAGE ${msg} : ${l}`);
}
```

And I get the following output:

```
hello world
MEMORY_USAGE before express import : rss 19.03 MB, heapTotal 4.77 MB, heapUsed 2.95 MB, external 1.03 MB, arrayBuffers 0.01 MB,
MEMORY_USAGE after express import : rss 28.49 MB, heapTotal 14.83 MB, heapUsed 5.96 MB, external 1.32 MB, arrayBuffers 0.03 MB,
MEMORY_USAGE after clear express : rss 28.5 MB, heapTotal 14.83 MB, heapUsed 5.97 MB, external 1.32 MB, arrayBuffers 0.03 MB,
```

I must have missed something super trivial, but I don't see what... Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to make Garbage Collector run?

```
if (global.gc){
  global.gc();
}
```

For that to work, you need to start the node process with `--expose-gc`

```
node --expose-gc index.js
```